# Display problem after switching to GNOME3 from unity in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome

So I switched my desktop environment from Unity to GNOME3 in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried using both display managers (lightdm default in Unity, gdm3 as gnome recommendation). However my display seems to be broken. I am attaching a screenshot for clarification[image: I can't use any of those options]

Comment: Your question says you're using 16.04, but you used 14.04 as tag! why?

Comment: @Anwar Because 16.04 tag didn't show up and I don't have enough rep to create a tag :)

Comment: Then it was better not to use confusing tag. There must be a browser problem because 16.04 is a created and much used tag [see here](https://askubuntu.com/tags). Anyway, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is associated with gtk-theme you're using, not with display manager. That theme is incompatible. I suggest using other theme.

To switch to default Adwaita theme, which should work always in GNOME, use this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita'
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I had just been  scratching my head about what could have gone wrong!!

Comment: @SudipBhandari Glad it helped. Also note that you can use other compatible theme beside Adwaita. Just change the name or use gnome-tweak-tool etc

Comment: Anwar Since chat requires at least 20 rep which I don't have as of now... I am posting a  link to my other problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/912962/cant-seem-to-get-syndameon-working-properly-disable-touchpad-while-typing

Comment: @SudipBhandari I checked that question. Unfortunately I'm not experienced with that question